# Example of a finite group $G$ with no non-trivial homomorphism into $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question is perhaps clear from title:

Is there an example of a finite group $G$ which has no non-trivial homomorphism into ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: You should look at simple groups. Clearly the abelian ones won't give you examples, but I think the first nonabelian one, $A_5$, works.

Comment: Seconding Owen Sizemore's comment. IIRC the irreducible representations of $A_5$ have dimensions 1,4,5,3,3. The 1-dimensional rep is trivial, so you cannot build anything non-trivial out of it. The corresponding list for $S_5$ is $1,1,4,4,6,5,5$. The duplicated dimensions are due to tensoring with the sign character, and those become equal when restricted to $A_5$. IIRC the 6-dimensional rep of $S_5$ splits into a sum of two non-isomorphic 3-dim reps of $A_5$.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, this list shows that any homomorphism from $S_5$ to $GL_n(\Bbb{C})$, $n<4$ comes from a sum of trivial/sign characters and therefore has kernel containing $A_5$.

Comment: Actually I think $S_4$ already works. Its irreducible $\le2$-dimensional representations are the two characters and the 2-dimensional rep of $S_3$ inflated via the isomorphism $S_4/V_4\simeq S_3$. All those components have $ V_4$ in the kernel.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But doesn't the sign map $S_4 \to \{\pm I\}\subset GL_2$ count as a non-trivial homomorphism?

Comment: The necessary condition on group should be that $G=[G,G]$ otherwise abelian quotient will give non-trivial homomorphisms.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, pGroups and @Omnomnomnom. My bad. For some reason I was looking for *injective* homomorphisms:-) So $A_5$ seems to be the smallest case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice way to see that $A_5$ works: begin by noting that any non-trivial homomorphism $\phi:A_5 \to GL_2$ must be injective, since $A_5$ is simple.  However, the Klein group $V_4 \subset A_5$ consists of $3$ commuting elements of order $2$.

Because they commute, the matrices corresponding to these $3$ elements must be simultaneously diagonalizable in $GL_2$, so we may suppose without loss of generality that they are diagonal.  However, there exist only two non-central diagonal matrices of order $2$.

Comment: A nice way of getting this done without a list of irreducible characters :-)

Comment: This is cool! $ $